# Undervolt laptop is disabling my dedicated GPU

Tags: undervolting

i have an acer E5-576G, core i5 8250U, graphic card nvidia MX150.
When i play games or develop in unreal engine, the cpu temperature goes sometimes to 80-90 degrees (max that i saw was 97)(15-25 ambient degrees).

So, i tried to undervolt using intel XTU and everything seems to work well, the volt decreases and my degrees too.
Except for one thing, i dont know why but have INTEL XTU installed makes my laptop ignore my dedicated graphic card.

Doesnt matter if i select using dedicated graphic always in Nvidia control Panel or not, it completly ignores my graphics and used the integrated one.

And that is not a problem of undervolting, because it happens if i just have the intel XTU opened and my CPU not undervolted. (it happens with ThorttleStop too)

The weird thing is that not always undervolt is disabling my dedicated gpu, somethimes it works but the ghz of my CPU works at half, 1600ghz (if my laptop is unplugged and undervolted). Instead of 3600 ghz (plugged & undervolted).

Its possible that Intel XTU is touching something related to graphic card?

im a bit worried because i dont know if i will can use my laptop on summer with this temp issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on a T580 (I5-8250 and MX150) and it works fine for me so my answer is:
No.
Try updating all drivers and the Intel XTU to the latest versions, maybe something was fixed since your attemp.

Answer (score 0):

For the intel XTU issue: its most likely just a install or version specific bug. I would reinstall that program and see if that works. Its also possible that the GPU and CPU are powered from the same central point and that this point voltage gets changed when you undervolt. you might have undervolted so far that the gpu can not function and does not turn on.

For the bigger issue

**Temperature**

Temps that high will kill your computer very quickly, try to never get past 50C. That laptop was built to have that temp range in mind. Stating that I have opened up hundreds of laptops to find thick wads of hair/dust/fibers stuck in the fins of the heat-sink which cause over-heating. If possible open the bottom of the laptop and clean out the dirt/hair/fibers from the fins of the heat-sink. If you have issues opening up the laptop I would take it to a repair shop and spend the ~$30 to have them clean it out before you fully fry your computer and have to spend ~$700 to get a new one.